# Python/SciPy version of Excel FInv function

Tags: python, scipy, probability

Hopefully an easy one.  Can anyone point me to the SciPy function that will calculate a right-tailed F Probability Distribution?

Like Excel's `=FINV(0.2, 1, 2)` that results in `3.555555556`.  Thanks, Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import scipy.stats

print scipy.stats.f.isf(0.2, 1, 2)  # => 3.5555555555555576
```

Comment: Similar useage for Excel CHIINV.  scipy.stats.chi2.isf(0.2, 1)  # => 1.642374415

Comment: A small clarification because this is the top result for "python f.inv" on Google. FINV returns the inverse of the RIGHT-tailed cumulative distribution function. In modern Excel versions F.INV (note the dot) is used, which returns the inverse of the LEFT-tailed CDF. To get the equivalent of F.INV, you can use scipy.stats.f.ppf